# NullPointerException when trying to call BroadcastReceiver not called

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

For some reason I am getting `NullPointerException`. I have gone through all the posts regarding this question. I wonder what am I missing here.

I intend to call a service, which will inturn a alarmmanager to activate a delayed intent that should be called at a particular time (not duration).

Activity Code, calling the service

```
    autoBookingIntent = new Intent(this,
            ScheduleAdvanceBookingService.class);        
    autoBookingIntent.putExtra("startTime", startTime);
    autoBookingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startService(autoBookingIntent) ;
```

Manifest

```
     <service
        android:name="com.taxeeta.ScheduleAdvanceBookingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
```

ScheduleAdvanceBookingService code

Exception here **==>**

```
package com.taxeeta;

public ScheduleAdvanceBookingService() {
    super("ScheduleAdvanceBookingService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, AutoAdvanceBooking.class);
    **==>**newIntent.putExtra("sourceLng",
            intent.getDoubleExtra("sourceLng", (Double) null));
    Date startTime = (Date) intent.getSerializableExtra("startTime");
    newIntent.putExtra("startTime", startTime);
    autoBookingAlarm = (AlarmManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    autoBookingPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            newIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    autoBookingAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime.getTime(),
            autoBookingPendingIntent);

    God.setAdvanceBookingNotification(this, God.CREATE_NOTIFICATION,
            startTime);
}
```

Why is intent null ?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like crying, it was a silly mistake on my part.

```
newIntent.putExtra("sourceLng",
            intent.getDoubleExtra("sourceLng", (Double) null));
```

This results in a `NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION`.